# Using SQL to Create Subtotal

Tags: sql

I have a table with following data:

| WO | Item | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| WO1 | RM1 | 5 |
| WO1 | RM1 | 3 |
| WO1 | FG1 | 2 |
| WO1 | FG1 | 1 |
| WO1 | FG1 | 4 |
| WO2 | RM1 | 2 |
| WO2 | RM1 | 1 |
| WO2 | RM1 | 6 |
| WO2 | FG1 | 5 |
| WO2 | FG1 | 3 |

I need a query which gives the following output:

| WO | Item | Qty | Item | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| WO1 | RM1 | 8 | FG1 | 7 |
| WO2 | RM1 | 9 | FG1 | 8 |

Please help me with an SQL code.

Comment: Welcome, what have you try, what problem you stumble, please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first.

Comment: Why are you repeating the item name in columns rather than just having `rm1_qty` and `fg1_qty`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation as follows:

```
SELECT WO,
       'RM1' AS ITEM_RM1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ITEM = 'RM1' THEN QTY END) AS RM1_QTY,
       'FG1' AS ITEM_FG1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ITEM = 'FG1' THEN QTY END) AS FG1_QTY
  FROM YOUR_TABLE
 WHERE ITEM  IN ('RM1','FG1')
GROUP BY WO
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot generate variable-column results with SQL, and it's not very handy for subsequent use either.

You can get the normalized results you want like this:

```sql
SELECT
    WO, Item, SUM(Qty) AS Qty
FROM
    The_table
GROUP BY
    WO, Item
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers, which lead me to JOIN two SELECT statements. I added percentage of RM (Raw Material) in FG (Finish Goods). Below has worked for me:

SELECT t1.WO, t1.RM, t1.RMQty, t2.FG, t2.FGQty, CAST(t1.RMQty*100/t2.FGQty as varchar) + '%' as Percentage
FROM
(SELECT WO, Item as RM, SUM(Qty) as RMQty FROM The_table WHERE Item='RM1' GROUP BY WO, Item) as t1
JOIN
(SELECT WO, Item as FG, SUM(Qty) as FGQty FROM The_table WHERE Item='FG1' GROUP BY WO, Item) as t2
ON t1.WO = t2.WO
ORDER BY WO